# Solr Query sort by function (Zend App_Solarium)

Tags: php, zend-framework, solr

I have a table with following fields:

1. created_date
2. published_date
3. sortbyp

I need sort based on another field:

```
if (sortbyp=1) {
  sort by "published_date" 
}
else {
  sort by "created_date"
}
```

I need to pass this to a Zend App_Solarium. Like:

```
$sort = array('mysql_id' => 'desc');
```

Comment: To make things clearer , i'll just paste MySQL query  ->  SELECT id, first_qualified, publish_date, from_date, 
CASE WHEN first_qualified =0
THEN publish_date
ELSE from_date
END sortdate
FROM  `jobs` 
ORDER BY  `sortdate` DESC

Answer (score 1):

Use SQL order by method: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp

Nothing else to say really.